Android 12, Copy OOB file programatically
I am wtitting an application using unity with suport of AAR, for the Meta quest 3 which is right now running Android 12. The goal of the app is to serve as an app distribution hub, downloading and installing other apps. As a part of installation the app, the app is being registered as device owner. The problem lies in fact that after installing the apk with packageInstaller i need to then copy over the OBB file to the respective folder, but while installing packages is not a problem, i am denied access to the obb folder.
This is the code for the AAR i use :

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageInstaller;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SilentInstaller {

    private static final String TAG = "SilentInstaller";
    private Context context;
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB buffer size

    public SilentInstaller(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Log.d(TAG, "SilentInstaller initialized.");
    }

    public void installApkWithObb(final String apkPath, final String obbPath, final String packageName, final boolean cleanup) {

        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Install APK
                installApk(apkPath, packageName, cleanup);

                // Copy OBB file
                copyObbFile(obbPath, packageName);
            }
        });
    }

    private void installApk(String apkPath, String packageName, boolean cleanup) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting APK installation in background thread.");

        File apkFile = new File(apkPath);
        if (!apkFile.exists()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "APK file does not exist: " + apkPath);
            return;
        }

        PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
        PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
        params.setAppPackageName(packageName);

        int sessionId;
        try {
            sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
            PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);

            try (OutputStream out = session.openWrite("base.apk", 0, -1);
                 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(apkFile)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
                int c;
                while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, c);
                }
                session.fsync(out);
            }

            session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
            session.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "Installation session committed in background thread.");

            // Check if cleanup is true, and delete the APK file
            if (cleanup) {
                if (apkFile.delete()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "APK file deleted after installation: " + apkPath);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to delete APK file: " + apkPath);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Installation failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public void copyObbFile(String obbPath, String packageName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting OBB file copy.");


        File obbFile = new File(obbPath);
        if (!obbFile.exists()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "OBB file does not exist: " + obbFile.getAbsolutePath());
            return;
        }

        // Directly access the OBB directory in /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/[package-name]
        File obbDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/obb/" + packageName);
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to create OBB directory at: " + obbDir.getAbsolutePath());

        if (!obbDir.exists()) {
            if (obbDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OBB directory successfully created at: " + obbDir.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create OBB directory: " + obbDir.getAbsolutePath());
                return;
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OBB directory already exists at: " + obbDir.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        // Check available storage space
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(obbDir.getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSizeLong() * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
        if (bytesAvailable < obbFile.length()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Not enough storage available to copy the OBB file. Available: " + bytesAvailable + " bytes, Needed: " + obbFile.length() + " bytes.");
            return;
        }

        File targetObbFile = new File(obbDir, obbFile.getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "Copying OBB file to: " + targetObbFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // Perform the file copy in smaller chunks
        try (FileChannel sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(obbFile).getChannel();
             FileChannel destChannel = new FileOutputStream(targetObbFile).getChannel()) {

            long position = 0;
            long transferred;
            long fileSize = sourceChannel.size();
            while (position < fileSize) {
                transferred = sourceChannel.transferTo(position, BUFFER_SIZE, destChannel);
                position += transferred;
                Log.d(TAG, "Transferred " + transferred + " bytes, position: " + position);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "OBB file copy completed. Total bytes transferred: " + position);

            // Verify the file size
            if (targetObbFile.length() != obbFile.length()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File copy failed: The copied file size (" + targetObbFile.length() +
                        " bytes) does not match the original file size (" + obbFile.length() + " bytes)");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "File copy successful: The copied file size matches the original.");

                // After successful copy, delete the old OBB file
                if (obbFile.delete()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Original OBB file deleted: " + obbFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to delete the original OBB file: " + obbFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to copy OBB file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private IntentSender createIntentSender(Context context, int sessionId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, InstallReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_SESSION_ID, sessionId);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                sessionId,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        );

        return pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
    }
}


additionally this are the permissions i have added so far
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Sadly with all that permissions i still cannot copy over the obb, or even create the folder.
Does any one know how i could do this ?
I have seen some file browsers that does have access to manipulate files in the oob filder so it would be great to learn how to do it.
Alternatively if a C# solution that could be implemented from the level of unity would working that would also be acceptable solution.
